# DialogResult in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently developing an application in C# using WPF, I have always only used WinForms. Normally if I want to ask the user a question instead of making my own dialogue I use

```cs
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(
    "My Message Question", "My Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

This is the first time that I have used a WPF form and `DialogResult` does not seem to be available. What do I use to get the same effect?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here is how you do the same in WPF:

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("My Message Question", "My Title", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    // Do this
}
```

Comment: Same thing, just shortened up:

if(MessageBox.Show("My Message Question", "My Title", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
//do this
}

Answer (score 6):

Use [MessageBoxResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messageboxresult) instead. And use the [MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox) class. But this message box will look pretty ugly "classic" style.

Another option would be to use [Extended WPF toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/MessageBox)

Yet another option would be to go [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19396) and download CrossTechnologySamples.exe then look into the VistaBridge project. I recommend you give a good look here because you will find other samples for other dialogs (like FileOpen, FileSave etc.) that do not exist by default in WPF.

Comment: The Microsoft.Win32 OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog work just fine in WPF...and are part of the .NET FW.

Comment: Aaron, DialogResults is not present in win32 ------------------Below code doesnt workf -----------if (ofdConfigFile.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)-----------am using open file dialog box